# Copy cell contents from one column to another column in the same worksheet---Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have account numbers in column E, and need those to replicate into column H for any cell that contains a value.

End result would be E1 = H1 and so on till all column E cells had been copied into coulmn H.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To whomever voted to close: insofar as VBA is programming, this is a programming-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub x()

    Call copy_acct_nums("E", "H")

End Sub

Private Sub copy_acct_nums(copy_from_col, copy_to_col)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
            .Cells(i, copy_to_col).Value = .Cells(i, copy_from_col).Value
        Next i

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you have multiple sheets to which you need to apply this code you could add a sheet argument to the copy subroutine. I will leave that to you :D

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
Sub copy()

  numrows = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
  Range("E1:E" & numrows & "").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("H1")

End Sub
```

The columns could have also been passed in as variables if needed.

```
Sub runCopy()

  Call copy("E", "H")

End Sub

Sub copy(col1, col2)

  numrows = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
  Range("" & col1 & "1:" & col1 & "" & numrows & "").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("" & col2 & "1")

End Sub
```